# The datum of a group is strictly more than the datum of a group up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

In a discussion regarding Mochizuki's work on the ABC conjecture which can be found [here](https://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/szpirostillaconjecture.pdf), Peter Scholze stated that

> "the
>   datum of a group is strictly more than the datum of a group up to isomorphism"

Explicitly, in what way is this true? Can someone give an example of a group satisfying the statement and explain precisely how one loses information up to isomorphism?

Comment: Isn't every automorphism "up to isomorphism" simply the identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from some old research of mine. I was (habitually) identifying groups up to isomorphism, and it made me miss a very obvious fact. The idea, out of context, is this:

If we think of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as the group of integer lattice points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then a *sublattice* $\Lambda$ will actually be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a group, but will represent something entirely different!

Here is a conrete example:

Consider $\mathbb{Z}^2 \leq \mathbb{R}^2$, shown in black. Then 
$\mathbb{Z}^2 \cong \Lambda \leq \mathbb{Z}^2$ is a sublattice (shown as red circles) carries *different* geometric information, even though the groups are (abstractly) the same.

[image: two isomorphic but nonequal lattices]

Long story short, me identifying the two different embeddings of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ led to a headache that was quickly resolved when I finally realized that there's more to a group than its isomorphism class.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Wouldn't $\mathbb{Z}\cong 2\mathbb{Z}$ fit as well as example?

Comment: Yes. But in 2 dimensions the lattices FEEL more different since you can have them rotated as well as stretched. Of course the mathematics is the same either way